# How to create a `PSObject` in PowerShell

Tags: .net, shell, powershell

When I heard about the [cool properties and methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject_members%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of `PSObject`s on MSDN, I thought it would be cool to try them out.

#### That's what I've done:

Firstly, I created a new instance of the type `PSObject`.

Then I looked for all those cool members using [Get-Member](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx) (but they weren't there):

```
PS .> $plainObj = New-Object PSObject

PS .> $plainObj | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
ToString    Method     string ToString()
```

## The Problem:

There's no `BaseObject` property - and no `AsPSObject()` method. All the cool members aren't there. But why?

Get-Member tells me that my objects is kind (`TypeName`) of `PSCustomObject` instead of `PSObject`. And `PSCustomObject` doesn't have all these cool members.

But I don't want `$plainObj` to be a kind of `PSCustomObject` - I want it to be a kind of `PSObject`.

## My Questions:

- Why is `$plainObj` a kind of `PSCustomObject` although I explicitly
  used `PSObject` as `-TypeName` at `$plainObj New-Object PSObject`?
  Any idea?
- How can I get `$plainObj` to be a kind of `PSObject` and not a kind of `PSCustomObject`?

---

> **@RussC** Even if I use your script - that's the result:
>
> ```
> PS .> $plainObj = New-Object PSObject -property @{ title = 'fridojet' };
> $plainObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Colour -Value Blue
>
> PS .> $plainobj | Get-Member
>
>
>    TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
>
> Name        MemberType   Definition
> ----        ----------   ----------
> Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
> GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
> GetType     Method       type GetType()
> ToString    Method       string ToString()
> Colour      NoteProperty System.String Colour=Blue
> title       NoteProperty System.String title=fridojet
> ```

---

> **@RussC** Now I managed to create an object which is not kind of `PSCustomObject`:
>
> ```
> PS .> New-Object Object
> ```
>
> But even then, I'm not able to create a `PSObject` (with a `BaseObject` property and so on):
>
> ```
> PS .> [PSObject]::AsPSObject((New-Object Object)) | Get-Member
>
>
>    TypeName: System.Object
>
> Name        MemberType Definition
> ----        ---------- ----------
> Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
> GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
> GetType     Method     type GetType()
> ToString    Method     string ToString()
> ```

Comment: Can you tell us which of these methods you're actually trying to use ?

Comment: @RussC What do you mean by that?

Comment: Your question states that you've "heard about cool properties and methods"; I was wondering if there was any specific one that you wanted to test ?

Comment: Do you mean: "Do I use `-property` **or** do I use `Add-Member` to add propertys to my object?" - Then my answer is: I use both of them - At first I add the `title` property using `-property` and then I add the `Colour` property using `Add-Member`. I just took the code of your answer.

Comment: ... Oh now I know what you mean. - No, there wasn't just one specific one, but I think the `AsPSObject()` method and the `BaseObject` property are imho the most interesting ones.

Comment: I've updated my original answer with some detail for you.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that it has nothing to report because it's not wrapping anything.

If you create a new [PSObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject) without wrapping another object, or providing any default members, then it will create a [PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0).

As MSDN states for a PSCustomObject: "Serves as a placeholder object that is used when the PSObject constructor, which has no parameters, is used."

If you do this for example:

```
$plainObj = New-Object PSObject -property @{ title = 'fridojet' }
$plainObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Colour -Value Blue
```

Then $plainObj should be a PSObject.

As PSObject is a static casting call,

```
$date = Get-Date
$pso = PSObject.AsPSObject($date)
```

or

```
$obj = New-Object object -property @{ title = "fridojet" }
$pso = PSObject.AsPSObject($obj)
```

BaseObject on the other hand returns the baseclass of the PSObject.

Using the second example above:

```
$obj = New-Object object -property @{ title = "fridojet" }
$pso = PSObject.AsPSObject($obj)
$end = $pso.BaseObject
```

In this case, $end should be an Object; not a PSObject; if you use the Get-Date one, $end should be a DateTime type.

I'm hoping that using this method would actually return a type of PSObject, not PSCustomObject.

However, the advantage of these properties and methods is dubious anyway. The main reason for using a PSObject wrapper is for when you're passing objects around a lot of .NET classes.

If you're just doing it experimentally then it doesn't give you anything that you don't already know.

This blog post shows some reasons why you would use PSObject, especially in a scenario where you're iterating a lot of objects via a .NET class: *[Custom object gotchas](http://cjoprey.wordpress.com/archived/custom-object-gotchas/)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried something like this, but it is and stays a `PSCustomObject`. Any other idea?

Comment: PS: I've tested out your script and I've posted some details of your script's results at the end of my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by `object` in `$obj = New-Object` **`object`** `-property @{` *(...)* `}`? Is there a special meaning or is `object` just a placeholder for a `TypeName`?

Comment: I can use `AsPSObject()` that way: `$pso = [PSObject]::AsPSObject($plainobj)`. But even if I explicitly use the `AsPSObject()` casting method in order to get a `PSObject`: The result of `AsPSObject()` is an `PSCustomObject` too! W-T-F?!?

Comment: ... I added some information concerning that to the bottom of my question text: Although, now I'm able to create an object which is not kind of `PSCustomObject` indeed, I'm not able to create a `PSObject`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but for anyone who is coming across this post trying to access the `PSObject`s properties and methods directly in PowerShell:

I noticed the same behavior in PowerShell 5.1 (as reported by OP) that even when explicitly calling the `PSObject` constructor (and when wrapping an object or when using `[PSObject]::AsPSObject()`) the PowerShell reports it to be of type `PSCustomObject` or the wrapped type:

```
$foo = [System.Management.Automation.PSObject]::new()
$foo.GetType().FullName
# returns: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
$foo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Colour -Value Blue
$foo.GetType().FullName
# returns: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

# Wrapping a System.Random
$bar = [System.Management.Automation.PSObject]::new((New-Object -TypeName System.Random))
$bar -is [System.Management.Automation.PSObject]
# returns: True
$bar.GetType().FullName
# returns: System.Random
```

and does not provide the properties or methods [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) provides.
But inspecting the result further with [`Get-Member -Force`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-5.1#-force):

```
$foo | Get-Member -Force
<#
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                                                                                                                                                         
----        ----------   ----------                                                                                                                                                         
pstypenames CodeProperty System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] pstypenames{get=PSType...
psadapted   MemberSet    psadapted {ToString, Equals, GetHashCode, GetType}                                                                                                                 
psbase      MemberSet    psbase {ToString, Equals, GetHashCode, GetType}                                                                                                                    
psextended  MemberSet    psextended {Colour}                                                                                                                                                
psobject    MemberSet    psobject {BaseObject, Members, Properties, Methods, ImmediateBaseObject, TypeNames, get_BaseObject, get_Members, get_Properties, get_Methods, get_ImmediateBaseO...
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                                                     
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                                                  
GetType     Method       type GetType()                                                                                                                                                     
ToString    Method       string ToString()                                                                                                                                                  
Colour      NoteProperty string Colour=Blue   
#>
```

shows that there are additional members, one of them being `psobject` which is documented as:

> PSObject: The adapter that converts the base object to a PowerShell PSObject object.

and it of type `System.Management.Automation.PSMemberSet` but provides similar properties and methods:

```
$foo.psobject | Get-Member
<#
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSMemberSet

Name                MemberType Definition                                                                                                                                                   
----                ---------- ----------                                                                                                                                                   
CompareTo           Method     int CompareTo(System.Object obj), int IComparable.CompareTo(System.Object obj)                                                                               
Copy                Method     psobject Copy()                                                                                                                                              
Equals              Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                                               
GetHashCode         Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                                            
GetMetaObject       Method     System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject IDynamicMetaObjectProvider.GetMetaObject(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression parameter)                                      
GetObjectData       Method     void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context), void ISerializable.GetObje...
GetType             Method     type GetType()                                                                                                                                               
ToString            Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider formatProvider), string IFormattable.ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvid...
BaseObject          Property   System.Object BaseObject {get;}                                                                                                                              
ImmediateBaseObject Property   System.Object ImmediateBaseObject {get;}                                                                                                                     
Members             Property   System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfoCollection[System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo] Members {get;}                                                
Methods             Property   System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfoCollection[System.Management.Automation.PSMethodInfo] Methods {get;}                                                
Properties          Property   System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfoCollection[System.Management.Automation.PSPropertyInfo] Properties {get;}                                           
TypeNames           Property   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[string] TypeNames {get;}                                                                                           
#>
```

and allows for example enumerating the properties of a `PSCustomObject` (or any other type created in a scripting environment as [everything is `PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/ets/overview?view=powershell-5.1#the-psobject-class)) :

```
$foo.psobject.Properties
<#
MemberType      : NoteProperty
IsSettable      : True
IsGettable      : True
Value           : Blue
TypeNameOfValue : System.String
Name            : Colour
IsInstance      : True
#>
```